# How do I add a user to my Firebase DB with it's unique id when I first create a user for authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This may seem like an obvious question, but i'm having trouble creating a user inside of my Firebase db. I'm very new to firebase and coding for that matter.

How I understand it to be is when a user clicks the sign up button, a user with the newly authenticated uid will be created under 'object/users". However the user is always null. In the [google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) it says that sometimes the user is null because it hasn't finished initializing the user. And to put it inside of `onAuthStateChanged`. This works, however, if I did this a user would be created/overwritten every time they log in or log out.

I suppose what I'm looking for is some solution to create a user inside of my firebase db when a user first signs up with valid information.

Here is my code:

```
  function LoginCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    $scope.txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
    $scope.btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
    $scope.btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
    $scope.btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');


    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

    });

    btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const email = txtEmail.value;
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

        createUser();
    });

    function createUser() {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        if (user != null) {
            const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');
            const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child("users/" + user.uid);
            dbRefList.set({
                name: "jim",
            });
        } 
    }

    btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            console.log(firebaseUser);
            btnLogout.classList.remove('hide');
            btnLogin.classList.add('hide');
        } else {
            console.log('not logged in');
            btnLogout.classList.add('hide');
            btnLogin.classList.remove('hide');
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in these three lines:

```
const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
createUser();
```

You are firing off `createUser()` too soon. In the above code fragment, this happens right after starting the (asynchronous) registration process – the SDK never had a chance to actually create the user in the auth database!

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns a promise, as reflected in your local variable. What you need to do here is *chaining* the two calls, i.e. start the database manipulation *after* the promise is fulfilled.

Try this:

```
// inside the click handler
btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .then(user => createUser(user)) // <-- important!
        .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
});

function createUser(user) {
    // no need for currentUser if you pass it in as an argument
    if (user) {
        ...
    }
}
```